# Can you represent neutron as stable superposition of decay products?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrons, subatomic

In this article ([here](http://arnold-neumaier.at/physfaq/topics/unstable.html)) it says that unstable particles can be represented as a stable superposition of the decay products. It says this representation is most relevant for when resonances only appear as resonances in cross-section curves, so the unstable particles are not observable (resolvable in time). It says Gamov states are a way of representing unstable particles in the limit of decay going to 0, and uses neutrons as an example for this.

I was wondering if you could instead still represent a neutron as a stable superposition of its decay products (e.g. proton, electron and electron anti-neutrino)? I'm guessing not since I don't know how this would be able to be linked to neutron decay via the weak interaction of quarks changing flavour.

Comment: Resonances are mostly considered for strongly decaying short-lived states, where you can measure and tally all decay products. The decay you mention corresponds to a lifetime of 15 minutes!! And the neutrino is unobservable. Hardly a meaningful context for this formalism...

Comment: Could you elaborate? Is it purely a convenience reason why neutrons are never considered in this way, or is there a theoretical barrier?

Comment: Also why is the neutrino unobservable in this case since neutrinos have been detected before?

Comment: Particle physics texts explain it. A *short-lived* resonance is only visible through invariant mass plots of products. the separation between convenience/practicality and theory is thin. Neutrinos are very hard to detect directly, especially the low energy ones of neutron decay... You'd detect one in a gazillion....